# Probably - PDF of two random variables

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

Suppose $X$ and $Y$ are iid random variables, both standard Cauchy-distributed (median is zero and scale parameter is $1$). Find the PDF of the mean of $X$ and $Y$,

$Z= \frac12(X+Y)$

I've been stuck on this one trying to figure out what to do. I think I should apply convolution but I don't know where to go from there

Comment: Hint: Can you compute the characteristic function of $X$? Of $Z$?

Answer (score 3):

Sure, convolution is one tool to apply to a sum distribution.   However, before doing so, as Did suggests in the comments, it may often be worth while examining the [characteristic function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Characteristic_function_%28probability_theory%29).

*Among* the [properties of a characteristic function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Characteristic_function_%28probability_theory%29#Properties), we know that the characteristic function of the sum of independent random variables, is equal to the product of the characteristic function of each variable.

$${\raise{0.25ex}\varphi_{[(X+Y)/2]}}(t) = {\raise{0.25ex}\varphi_X}(t/2)\cdot{\raise{0.25ex}\varphi_Y}(t/2)$$

So, is ${\raise{0.25ex}\varphi_Z}(t)$ a [recognisable characteristic function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Characteristic_function_%28probability_theory%29#Examples)?

Answer (score 1):

**Another way**

Let $2Z=U$, we have $U=X+Y$ and
$$f_U(u)=\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}f_Y(u-x)f_X(x)dx=\frac{1}{\pi^2}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\frac{1}{1+(u-x)^2}\cdot\frac{1}{1+x^2}dx$$
Set $$g(z)=\frac{1}{(1+(u-z)^2)(1+z^2)}$$ The residue of $g(z)$ at $z=i$,
$$\text{Res}_{z=i}\,\,g(z)=\frac{1}{2i(1-(i-u)^2)}$$
and the residue of $g(z)$ at $z=u+i$,
$$\text{Res}_{z=u+i}\,\,g(z)=\frac{1}{2i(1+(i+u)^2)}$$
By application of [Residue theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=Residue_theorem&oldid=190379063), we have
$$f_U(u)=\frac{1}{\pi^2}\oint_{C}g(z)dz=\frac{1}{\pi^2}\times 2\pi i\left( \frac{1}{2i(1-{{(i-u)}^{2}}}+\frac{1}{2i(1+{{(i+u)}^{2}}} \right)=\frac{2 }{\pi({{u}^{2}}+4)}$$